# Need materials to learn Ext JS Bar Charts

Tags: extjs

I have few tasks in Ext JS charts. Spent lot of time on Internet for the tutorials. But I didn't get it correctly. So Could any one please suggest me few websites to learn that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you ask a specific question or give an example of a code?
It will be much easier.
Have you looked at the examples provided in the documentation?
Maybe look at this - https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#charts